# MassTransit. Handle Deserialization exception

Tags: .net, exception, apache-kafka, deserialization, masstransit

It wasn't long ago that I started working with Mastransit and was faced with the need to intercept the deserialization error of an incoming message. Unfortunately, after several days of trying, I still didn't succeed. I'm asking for help. I will describe the situation.

The client sends messages to my application, the exchange goes through Kafka. The version of the MassTransit library is 8.0.13. It happens that the client sends invalid Json to Kafka and in my service an error is occurring. I need to intercept this error and send a new message in a certain format to the Kafka topic for the client. At first, I tried to implement this through filters and middleware, errors that occur after deserialization are already in consumer, they intercept, but there is no deserialization error, it occurs before it gets into consumer. Then I decided to write a custom serializer that will calling _topicProducer<ResponseMessageType>.Produce(message); but there was a difficulty with dependencies. I need a ServiceProvider, I built it via ServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider() and then received the necessary TopicProducer from it for a custom deserializer, but the error falls "The ReceivePipeConfiguration can only be used once."

Tell me please, maybe I chose the wrong approach at all and need to do it differently? How can I intercept a deserialization error and take some action based on it?

Here is my configuration:

```
public static void AddMassTransitConfiguration(
    this IServiceCollection services, 
    IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(busCfg =>
    {
        busCfg.UsingInMemory((context, config) =>
        {
            config.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });

        busCfg.AddRider(rider =>
        {
            rider.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>(); 
            rider.AddConsumer<OrderProcessingResultConsumer>();

            rider.AddProducer<OrderForProcessingMessage>(
                configuration
                    .GetSection("OrderForProcessingProducer")
                    .GetSection("Topic").Value,
                (context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.SetValueSerializer(
                        new MassTransitJsonSerializer<OrderForProcessingMessage>());
                });
           
            rider.AddProducer<OrderResultMessage>(
                configuration.GetSection("OrderResultProducer").GetSection("Topic").Value,
                (context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.SetValueSerializer(new MassTransitJsonSerializer<OrderResultMessage>()); 
                });

            var isDevelopment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") !=
                                Environments.Development;

            Action<IKafkaHostConfigurator>? kafkaHostConfigurator = isDevelopment ? hostConfig =>
                {
                    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") !=
                        Environments.Development)
                    {
                        hostConfig.UseSasl(saslConf =>
                        {
                            saslConf.Mechanism = SaslMechanism.ScramSha256;
                            saslConf.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslPlaintext;
                            saslConf.Username = configuration.GetSection("Kafka")
                                .GetSection("User").Value;
                            saslConf.Password = configuration.GetSection("Kafka")
                                .GetSection("Password").Value;
                        });
                    }
                }
                : null;

            rider.UsingKafka((ctx, kafkaCfg) =>
            {
                SetMainConsumer(kafkaCfg, configuration, kafkaHostConfigurator, ctx);

                kafkaCfg.Host(configuration.GetSection("Kafka").GetSection("Host").Value, kafkaHostConfigurator);
                kafkaCfg.TopicEndpoint<OrderMessage>(
                    configuration.GetSection("OrderConsumer").GetSection("Topic").Value,
                    configuration.GetSection("OrderConsumer").GetSection("ConsumerGroup").Value,
                    endpointCfg =>
                    {
                        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                        var beeKeeperIntegrationService = 
                            serviceProvider.GetService<IBeeKeeperIntegrationService>();

                        endpointCfg.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                        endpointCfg.SetValueDeserializer(new CustromMassTransitJsonDeserializer(beeKeeperIntegrationService));
                        endpointCfg.ConfigureConsumer<OrderConsumer>(ctx);
                    }
                );

                kafkaCfg.TopicEndpoint<OrderProcessingResultMessage>(
                    configuration.GetSection("OrderProcessingResultConsumer").GetSection("Topic").Value,
                    configuration.GetSection("OrderProcessingResultConsumer").GetSection("ConsumerGroup").Value,
                    endpointCfg => 
                    {
                        endpointCfg.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                        endpointCfg.SetValueDeserializer(new MassTransitJsonDeserializer<OrderProcessingResultMessage>());
                        endpointCfg.ConfigureConsumer<OrderProcessingResultConsumer>(ctx);
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the receive endpoint as raw JSON, and use whatever message type to deserialize.

```
endpoint.UseRawJsonSerializer();
```

Use following link for detailed information : https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/serialization

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).